# Magento code or extension to add coupon code in last step of onestep checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, coupon

We are looking for a clean, easy, close to core solution  to add coupon code in last step of onestep checkout

Question: What's the best extension or code could we could use to accomplish this

What it should do is

1. show the discount box in the very last step
2. on enter or on submit, it should reload the last step in onestep checkout (na ajax necessary)
3. On the server compute the discount & show the last step again in onestep checkout

[image]

many thanks in advance

FYI
When a client goes directly to checkout (instead of via cart) - they are never confronted with a box to enter a coupon code. We have just launched a national ad - and the below article is true ... it is almost ridiculous how many emails we receive on this matter: "Hi, we would like to buy but cannot find where to enter the coupon code"

http://www.commandc.com/2014/01/29/top-reasons-for-cart-abandonment-2-difficulty-with-promo-codes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found

**Both add a new step**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-coupon-code-from-your-checkout-process.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/checkout-discount-coupon-step.html

**Incorporates it under totals table**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/discount-coupon-code-checkout-page.html

**Our choice**
We ended up using the veriosn that incorporates in last review step (so not as separate step). But we needed to write our own code based on the extension that was not very well tested and seemd a little old

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of extensions that include the coupon code on the checkout page. Have a look [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=one%20step&pl=0).

Comment: Thanks @sr_magento. We actually tried many of them. And all have some flaws. First - there apparently is 1 programmer that onze wrote some code and has been copied amongst all the other extensions (even the remarks in code). And we dont want the coupon as a separate step (annoying or when you o not have a couponcode)