# coupon code at checkout

Tags: checkout, coupon

When a product is added to the cart, a coupon code field is available. But after pressing continue to checkout, the coupon code field is no longer available. Anyway to make it appear through other steps in the checkout process?

Answer (score 1):

magento only `provide   coupon field at  checkout cart page`
(checkout/cart) ,it `donot provide coupon field at onepage (checkout/onepage)`.

If you want to add this last step of onepage then follow the link
[Magento code or extension to add coupon code in last step of onestep checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16373/magento-code-or-extension-to-add-coupon-code-in-last-step-of-onestep-checkout)